# How to define multiple dispatch, when we have so many structs?

Tags: julia

If we have a few structs, using multiple dispatch isn't a problem. 
But when we have so many struct, how to use multiple dispatch? 
For example, we have N structs like this:

```
struct An
   a::Float64
end
```

And a function like:

```
f!(a::Ai) = exp(Ai.a)
```

When N is large, it will be a headache.
Consider that this function is simple and easy! A function could be so large!

Comment: If you have a lot of structs that are almost identical and do almost the same thing, maybe you don't need them all? Why do you have a lot of very similar structs? Can you use parametric types instead? If you have large functions, can you separate out the common code, instead of re-writing the whole thing for every type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the function definition is the same for all the structs, you could define them as a concrete type of some abstract type, and leave only one function that dispatches on the abstract type:

```
julia> abstract type Allmystructs end

julia> struct A1 <: Allmystructs
           a::Float64
       end

julia> struct A2 <: Allmystructs
           a::Float64
       end
julia> f(A :: Allmystructs) = exp(A.a)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test1 = A1(5)
A1(5.0)

julia> test2 = A2(8)
A2(8.0)

julia> f(test1)
148.4131591025766

julia> f(test2)
2980.9579870417283
```

Of course, this may not be what you are looking for if the function definition for each type of struct is different. In that case, metaprogramming can be your friend.

Edit: Typos.

Comment: A much better solution than using `eval`!

Comment: This is a fine solution, but it should be pointed out that generally abstract types should be used for things that are conceptually the same but structurally different, not things that are structurally the same. Parametric types or composition are probably better alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate the names of your structs in a loop, and use `@eval` to generate and evaluate code for each of them:

```
julia> for S in [:A1, :A2, :A3]
           @eval begin
               struct $S
                   a::Float64
               end
               f(x::$S) = exp(x.a)
           end
       end

julia> A2(2)
A2(2.0)

julia> f(A2(2))
7.38905609893065
```

I here defined the structs in the same place, because I was trying it out in the console.

But there might be a better alternatives to this.  `eval` is usually considered a sign of suboptimal design.

Comment: Is it necessary to define both functions and structs in the same loop?

Comment: No it is not.necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when code has a lot of very similar structs, this suggests that maybe [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is an alternative.

As an example, suppose we have a colored geometric shape library with a lot of different structs:

```
const Point = Tuple{Float64, Float64}

struct Disc
    center::Point
    radius::Float64
    red::Float64
    green::Float64
    blue::Float64
end

struct Rectangle
    topleft::Point
    bottomright::Point
    red::Float64
    green::Float64
    blue::Float64
end

# ... etc., e.g. Triangle, Hexagon
```

Now suppose we want to introduce a `luminance()` function which returns the perceived luminance of the color of the shape. One way is to define a method for each struct, but since the methods are all the same, we can also do:

```
const Shape = Union{Disc, Rectangle, Triangle, Hexagon}
luminance(shape::Shape) = 0.299*shape.red + 0.587*shape.green + 0.114*shape.blue)
```

This is still a little annoying because we need to have all the shapes available in one place in order to list them. Adding new shapes would be a hassle. So indeed, we can make an `abstract type Shape end` and have each shape subtype it, as suggested in the accepted answer. But in many ways, this approach is still unsatisfactory, because it constrains all future `Shape`s to share the same layout!

A better way to approach this problem is to decouple the `red`, `green`, and `blue` properties shared by all the colored shapes. Thus we introduce a type hierarchy as:

```
const Point = Tuple{Float64, Float64}

struct Color
    red::Float64
    green::Float64
    blue::Float64
end

abstract type Figure end

struct Disc <: Figure
    center::Point
    radius::Float64
end

struct Rectangle <: Figure
    topleft::Point
    bottomright::Point
end

struct ColoredShape{F <: Figure}
    figure::F
    color::Color
end
```

Now, instead of using `Rectangle((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` to represent a gray rectangle, we would use `ColoredShape(Rectange((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)), Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))`. Instead of defining multiple identical `luminance` methods, we would define it just once for the `Color` struct. (You could also, optionally, define another method for `ColoredShape` that delegates to the property `color`, but this is only one additional method instead of `N`!) This pattern also allows the functionality we define for colors to be reused across other contexts, besides colored shapes.

In general, it is preferable to split concepts down to the smallest digestible pieces for re-usability and understandability. If there are lots of very similar structs, such that defining functions for all of them seems to be a chore, this would suggest that there could possibly be some shared functionality to factor out.